# Dell XPS 13 vs. Dell Latitude 7xxx

Tags: laptop

Is there a general difference between a XPS13 with i7 and a Latitude 7xxx with i7 (besides 1 inch different display size)?
They have so many notebooks and I don't see the differences.

Answer (score 1):

**XPS 13**

*Processor* - i7-8550u

*RAM* 16GB

*SSD* 512GB - 1TB

*Display* - 13.3'' 4K Ultra HD (3840 x 2160) InfinityEdge touch display

*Ports*

- 2x Thunderbolt™ 3 with PowerShare DC-In & DisplayPort
- 1x USB-C 3.1 with PowerShare, DC-In & DisplayPort 1x card reader
- 1x headset jack
- 1x Noble lock slot

**Latitude 7xxx series**

Processor - i7-7600u

RAM 8-32GB

SSD 128-512GB

Display -

- 14" HD (1366 x 768) Anti-Glare, Camera & Mic, WLAN/WWAN Capable, Non-touch
- 14" FHD (1920 x 1080) Anti-Glare, Camera & Mic, WLAN/WWAN Capable, Non-touch
- 14" FHD (1920 x 1080) Anti-Glare, IR Camera & Mic, WLAN/WiGig Capable, Non-touch
- 14" FHD (1920 x 1080) Touch, Corning® Gorilla® Glass 4, Camera & Mic, WLAN/WWAN Capable
- 14" QHD (2560 x 1440) Touch, Corning® Gorilla® Glass 4, Cam & Mic, WLAN/WiGig, Narrow Bezel, CF

Ports

- 1 DisplayPort over USB Type C™ with optional Thunderbolt™ 3 capability
- 1 Headset/mic combo jack
- 1 uSD 4.0 Memory card reader
- 3 USB 3.1 Gen 1 (one with PowerShare)
- 1 HDMI
- 1 RJ-45
- 1 External uSIM card tray option
- 1 Optional SmartCard Reader and Touch Fingerprint Reader
- 1 Noble Wedge Lock slot

I just took a basic config from Dell's site for comparison, depending on allowed options, these could vary a bit.  The Latitude series has more build options while the XPS is limited to by which model you choose.